# Running SoX from Processing/Java on Windows computer

Tags: java, windows, cmd, processing, sox

This might be an easy one - but it's driving me nuts at this point. I'm trying to run SoX from Processing which on my mac computer is running smoothly and with no problems. I need to migrate the code to a windows 7 machine but can't get it to work  for some reason. Talking to the terminal from processing works fine. I'm in the right folder (sketch data folder where SoX is also intalled) since I can run commands like "dir" etc. and get the right content printed  - but as soon as I try to run sox.exe nothing happens (getting an exit value 1). Running sox.exe straight from the cmd terminal works fine. Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
void playBackYear (){

soxPlay = "cmd /c sox.exe year.wav -d";
  println (soxPlay);
 try {
    File workingDir = new File(sketchPath("data"));
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(soxPlay, null, workingDir);
    p.waitFor(); 
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
      ); 
    String line; 
    while ( (line = reader.readLine ()) != null) 
    { 
      println(line);
    }
   int exitVal = p.waitFor();
   System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
  } 

  catch(IOException e1) {
   System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e1.getMessage());
   System.out.println( "error 1" );
  } 
  catch(InterruptedException e2) {
   System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e2.getMessage());
   System.out.println( "error 2" );
  } 

}
```

So the questions is what am I doing wrong here? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Step one should be to put something inside of those catch blocks. As of now you're hiding any errors you get.

Comment: @mattuck Have you tried [open()](https://processing.org/reference/open_.html) first ?

Comment: Hi Kevin and George, thanks so much for replying. I added some messages inside catch() block but it doesn't return any errors. Also tried the open() function before running the try(). No luck unfortunately. I wonder how can I tell if it is actually opening up SoX and what would the error code 1 mean from the `int exitVal = p.waitFor(); System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);`

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small wrapper application that wraps sox binary in java. If you are interested in the full project, check it out on GitHub: [sox java wrapper project](https://github.com/corballis/sox-wrapper-java)

This is, how i have solved the problem:

```
private List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();
// add sox arguments to this list above

public void execute() throws IOException {
    File soxBinary = new File(soXBinaryPath);
    if (!soxBinary.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Sox binary is not available under the following path: " + soXBinaryPath);
    }

    arguments.add(0, soXBinaryPath);
    logger.debug("Sox arguments: {}", arguments);
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(arguments);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = null;
    IOException errorDuringExecution = null;
    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            logger.debug(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorDuringExecution = e;
        logger.error("Error while running Sox. {}", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        arguments.clear();
        if (process != null) {
            process.destroy();
        }
        if (errorDuringExecution != null) {
            throw errorDuringExecution;
        }
    }
}
```